# STTwitter Not Returning Anything Neither Success or Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sttwitter

I am having a very hard time here. There is one part in my application that STTwitter is successful and there is another part (using the same code) that does not return anything.

The part that does NOT work: `

```
-(IBAction)followTwitter:(id)sender {

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"twitter_on_file" ] == nil) {

    UIAlertView *allert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh!" message:@"You have not linked your twitter account quite yet! Head to My Account settins to do so." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [allert show];

} else {
    ACAccountStore *store1 = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [store1 accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    if ([twitterAccountType accessGranted]) {
        [store1 requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterAccountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

            arrayOfUsernames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            iosAccounts = [store1 accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];
            for (ACAccount *accou in iosAccounts) {
                [arrayOfUsernames addObject:accou.username];
            }

            NSString *usernameOnFile =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"twitter_on_file" ];
            int tracker = 0;

            for (NSString *username in arrayOfUsernames) {

                if ([username isEqualToString:usernameOnFile]) {
                    NSLog(@"Using twitter account: %@", username);
                    STTwitterAPI *twitterAPI = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithAccount:iosAccounts[tracker]];
                    [twitterAPI verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {
                        NSLog(@"Successfully authenticated the user");

                    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                        NSLog(@"Erorr: %@", error);

                    }];
                    NSLog(@"Twitter API: %@", twitterAPI);

                    [twitterAPI postFriendshipsCreateForScreenName:@"kickscaterer" orUserID:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *befriendedUser) {

                        NSLog(@"Befriend %@", befriendedUser);


                    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    }];
                } else {
                    tracker++;
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

}
`

The part that DOES work:

```
  STTwitterAPI *twitter= [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithAccount:iosAccounts[indexForAlert.row]];

        [twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {
            // ...
            NSLog(@"Username: %@", username);
            //  [self.tableView reloadData];


            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:twitter.userName forKey:@"twitter_on_file"];

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            // ...
        }];

        [twitter postFriendshipsCreateForScreenName:@"didi4" orUserID:nil successBlock:^(NSDictionary *befriendedUser) {

            NSLog(@"Befriend %@", befriendedUser);


        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `postFriendshipsCreateForScreenName:` method should be called **inside** the success block, at the same level than the log "Successfully authenticated the user".

Comment: Thanks so much for the respons! I tried this, however it still has yet to work.

Comment: Wait I think I found the problem.

Comment: Ok, so now it does in fact return something now, thanks to you. However, it returns an error: Your credentials do not allow access to this resource. This it strange considering I am using a local iOS account from settings.

Comment: I just tested the `postFriendshipsCreateForScreenName:` method with the Twitter account from iOS 8 Settings and it works as expected. Please try to reduce the issue to a simple and complete test case.